# How to perform linear regression on the starting points of a dataset using R

Tags: r, linear-regression

How do I perform a regression with Date contraints? I only want to perform a regression on the "non-zero" part of the data set.

The main issue is that columns 2 & 3 start at different `Dates` & i have written a loop that will perform a regression from a starting-point ( 2012-01-01) to 2013-12-31, adding a 6-month intervals at every iteration.

```
DATES <- c("201201/201206", "201201/201212", "201201/201306", "201201/201312")
```

How can i perform a regression so that uses the starting point of columns 2 & 3 at the given iteration?

Here is the `RETS` dataset:

```
RETS <- structure(c(0.0159, 0.0016, 0.0027, -0.0026, 0.0024, 0.0086, 
6e-04, 0.0024, -0.0052, 0.0039, 0.0111, 0.0053, 0.0037, -0.0026, 
-0.0011, 0.0083, -0.0051, -4e-04, -0.0035, -4e-04, 0.0088, 0.0015, 
0.014, -6e-04, 0.0025, 0.0029, 0.0013, -0.0074, 0.0074, -0.0013, 
-0.0046, 0.0111, 0.0027, 5e-04, -0.0033, 0.0045, 0.0022, 0.0017, 
0.0029, -0.0039, 0.0051, -0.003, -0.0041, -0.0146, 0.007, 0.0099, 
0.0039, 1e-04, 0.0181, -0.0011, 0.0059, 0.0014, 0.0039, -0.0029, 
-0.0017, -0.0072, 0.0033, 0.014, -0.0031, -0.0049, -0.0017, 0.0042, 
0.0073, -0.004, -0.01, -5e-04, -0.0113, -0.0168, 0.0081, 0.0131, 
-0.0119, -6e-04, 0.0148, -0.0034, -0.0064, 0.0017, -0.0084, 0.0038, 
0.0137, 0.007, 0.0016, -0.0037, 0.0063, -0.003, -0.0076, -0.0162, 
8e-04, -0.004, -0.006, 0.0021, -0.003, -0.0111, -0.0058, -0.0038, 
-0.0148, -0.0086, 0.0172, 0.0018, 5e-04, 0.002, -0.0033, 0.0121, 
-0.0145, -0.0022, -0.0252, -5e-04, 0.0076, 0.0225, 6e-04, 0.0079, 
-0.0127, 0.0115, -0.0065, 0.0107, 0.0102, 0.0019, 0.0097, -0.0016, 
-0.0225, 0.0077, -0.016, 0.0051, 0.009, -0.0029, 0.025, 0.003, 
0.0066, -0.0045, -0.0095, -0.0012, -0.0087, 2e-04, -0.0049, 0.0168, 
-0.0024, 0.0068, 0.0074, 0.0027, -0.0092, -0.0101, -0.0086, 2e-04, 
0.0164, 0.0185, 0, -0.007, -9e-04, -0.0069, 0.0198, 0.002, 0.0051, 
0.0012, 8e-04, 0.0016, -5e-04, 1e-04, 0.0011, 0.0074, 0.0013, 
1e-04, -0.003, 4e-04, -0.0082, 0.0061, 1e-04, -0.001, 8e-04, 
-0.0072, 0.0047, -9e-04, -8e-04, 0.0203, 0.0039, -0.0057, 0.0028, 
0.0034, 0.0152, 0.0045, -0.0034, -8e-04, 5e-04, 1e-04, -4e-04, 
-0.0015, -0.0106, -0.0056, 0.0094, -0.0046, 0.0026, 0.0011, 0.0041, 
0.0071, 1e-04, -0.0034, -0.0099, -0.0064, 6e-04, -0.0033, 0.0084, 
0.0101, 0.0045, -0.0026, -0.0167, 1e-04, -0.0139, -0.0029, 0.003, 
-6e-04, 0, 0.0104, -0.0089, 0.0021, 0.0078, -0.0227, -0.012, 
8e-04, 8e-04, -0.0035, -0.0135, -0.0017, 0.0049, 0.0202, 5e-04, 
0.0019, 0.0136, -0.0021, -0.0051, 0.008, 0.0047, 2e-04, -0.0049, 
-0.0015, 0.0018, 0.0034, 0.003, 4e-04, 0.0068, 5e-04, -0.0061, 
-0.0037, 0.0117, 0.0111, -0.0074, 0.0057, -0.0091, -0.0031, -0.0042, 
-0.0013, -0.0108, 0.017, 0.0256, -0.0023, 0.0044, -0.0027, -0.0029, 
0.0026, 0.008, -1e-04, -7e-04, 7e-04, -1e-04, 0.0064, 0.0022, 
0.0054, 0.0016, 3e-04, 0.0056, -0.0012, 0.004, -0.0039, -0.0025, 
0.0104, -0.0113, 0.0101, 8e-04, -0.0013, 0.0055, -2e-04, 0.0017, 
8e-04, 9e-04, -0.0012, 0.0075, -0.0125, -0.006, 0.0097, -0.019, 
0.0068, 0.0126, -0.002, 0.0033, 0.0053, 0.009, 0.0013, 0.0018, 
0.0042, 0.0038, -0.0023, 0.0015, 0.0053, -0.0013, -0.0055, -0.0023, 
0.007, -0.0086, 0.0081, -0.0042, 0.008, 0, 0.0031, -0.004, 0.0049, 
-0.0101, 0.004, -0.0045, 0.0067, 0.0034, 0.0123, 0.0033, -0.0025, 
-0.0231, 0.0148, -0.0146, -0.0063, 0.0087, 0.0044, 0.0103, 6e-04, 
0.0041, -0.0018, 0.0067, 0.0023, -0.0088, 0.0093, 0.0101, 0.0026, 
0.0051, 0.0046, -0.0029, 0.0032, 8e-04, 0.0103, 0.0054, -0.0047, 
0.0096, -1e-04, 0.0015, -0.0074, -0.0029, -8e-04, 0.006, -0.0065, 
0.0037, -0.0144, 0.0055, -0.0048, -0.014, 0.0091, 0.0127, 0, 
-0.0103, -0.0083, 0.0152, -0.0063, 0.0077, 0.0079, -0.0138, -0.0248, 
0.0032, -0.0127, 0.0096, 0.0099, 0.0059, -0.0041, 0.0058, -0.001, 
4e-04, 0.0108, 0.0057, 0.0072, 4e-04, 0.0136, 4e-04, 0.0038, 
-0.0037, 0.0026, 0.0055, 0.0018, 0.0019, -0.0021, -0.0037, 0.0024, 
0.001, -0.003, 0, 7e-04, 0.0116, 0.0017, -0.0014, -0.0057, -0.0032, 
0.0037, -0.0029, -0.0012, 0.003, -0.0052, -0.014, -0.0033, -0.0064, 
0.0049, -0.0062, 0.0091, 0.0034, -0.0038, -0.0161, 0.0035, 0.0016, 
-0.0032, 0.0045, 0.0083, 0.0012, 5e-04, 0.0096, 0.0074, 0.0031, 
-0.0026, 0.0023, 0.0058, 0.0045, 0.0116, -0.0017, -0.007, -0.0046, 
-0.0024, -0.0029, 0.0039, -0.0046, -0.0053, 0.0079, -0.001, -0.0092, 
0.0076, -0.0087, -0.0116, 7e-04, 0.0215, 0.0065, 0.004, -0.0073, 
0.014, 0.0067, 0.0067, 1e-04, 0.0058, -0.0048, 0.0033, 0.0046, 
0.0016, 0.0054, -0.005, -0.0028, 0.0024, 0.0035, -0.0031, 0.0051, 
-0.0127, 0.0135, 2e-04, -0.002, 0.0081, 0.0049, 0.0044, -0.0035, 
-0.0022, -0.0031, 0.0081, 0.005, -0.001, 3e-04, 0.0024, -7e-04, 
-0.0026, -0.0043, -1e-04, -0.0044, 0.0112, 0.0025, -0.0036, -0.0112, 
-0.0033, -1e-04, 0.0063, -0.0032, 0.0171, -0.0012, 0.0058, 0.0053, 
0.0022, 0.0051, -1e-04, -2e-04, 0.0047, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.1099, -0.089, 0.0323, 0.0322, -0.0339, -0.0962, 
-0.0225, 0.05, -0.0635, -0.0296, -0.0383, 0.0363, -0.0186, 0.03, 
-0.0033, 0.0144, -0.0047, 0.0374, 0.0608, 0.0467, 0.0159, -0.0097, 
0.0076, 0.038, -0.03, 0.0324, -0.0263, -0.027, -0.0083, -0.0106, 
0.014, 0.0087, 0.0083, 0.0139, -0.0218, -0.0159, -0.0052, -0.0029, 
-0.0804, -0.0057, 0.0363, -0.0038, -0.0083, -3e-04, -0.0104, 
0.0313, -0.0849, -0.1169, -0.0236, -0.0622, -0.0382, -0.0402, 
0.0524, 0.0394, -0.0547, 0, 0.014, 0.0381, -0.0096, -0.0565, 
0.0402, -0.0627, -0.0413, 0.0504, -0.0425, 0.0146, 0, -0.0015, 
-0.0134, 0.0099, -0.0124, -5e-04, -0.054, -0.0183, 0.0479, 0.0205, 
0.0011, -0.009, 0.033, 0.0772, -0.0105, 0.0623, -0.0218, 0.0163, 
0.0649, -0.0301, 0.012, -0.0906, -0.0245, 0.0168, -0.0145, 0.0659, 
0.0152, 0.0127, -0.0198, 0.0055, -0.0474, -0.0244, -0.0083, -0.0292, 
0.0056, -0.0116, 0, -0.002, 0.0205, -0.0453, 0.0011, 0.0168, 
0.0093, 0.1913, -0.0288, -0.0275, -0.0378, 0.0047, -0.0014, 0.0033, 
-0.0038, -0.0331, -0.0234, -0.039, 0.0448, -0.0105, 0.1259, -0.0085, 
0.0627, -0.0272, 0.0079, 0.0528, -0.0132, 0.0808, 0.0081, 0.008, 
0.0364, 0.0249, -0.0343, 0.0155, 0.0091, -0.0267, 0.0193, 0.0127, 
0.005, -0.0143, 0.0239, -0.0506, -0.0022, 0.0359, -0.0108, -0.0018, 
-0.0402, 0.0255, -0.0156, -0.0174, -0.0054, 0.0274, 0.0518, -0.0082, 
0.0356, 0.0229, -0.0122, 0.0526, 0.0232, 0.0134, -0.0243, -0.0275, 
-0.0083, 0.0097, -0.0159, 0.0361, 0.0029, 0.0084, 0.0148, 0.0295, 
-0.0517, 0.0146, -0.0083, -0.0403, -0.0545, 0.0189, 0.0143, -0.0138, 
-0.0035, -0.0102, -0.0315, 0.0197, 0.0211, -0.0063, 0.0215, -0.0162, 
-0.0415, -0.0055, 0.0052, 0.0044, -0.019, 0.0141, 0.0194, -0.0022, 
-0.0072, -0.0025, 0.0412, -0.0217, 0.0064, -0.011, -0.0269, -0.0015, 
-0.0144, -0.006, 0.0023, -0.026, -0.0046, -4e-04, -0.0233, 0.0032, 
0.0349, -0.0195, -0.002, -0.0043, 0.0327, 0.0312, 0.0118, -0.0197, 
-0.0097, 0.0369, 0.0163, -0.0221, -0.0321, 0.0151, -0.0108, -0.0353, 
0.0016, 0.0093, 4e-04, 0.005, 0.0011, 0.0272, 0.0048, 0.0293, 
-0.0122, 0.0561, -0.0228, -0.0261, -0.0247, 0.0086, -0.0029, 
-0.0133, 0.0052, 0.0093, -0.0174, -0.0177, 0.0046, -0.0187, -0.0039, 
-0.0195, -0.004, -0.0299, -0.0086, -0.0324, 0.0527, -0.0081, 
-0.0205, -0.0138, -0.0264, 0.0031, 0.0139, 0.0447, -0.0123, -0.0108, 
-0.0017, -0.0042, 0.0165, 0.0079, 0.0041, -0.0169, 0.0264, -0.0241, 
0.0129, -0.0037, 0.0207, 0.0089, -0.0028, -0.0161, 0.0045, -0.0061, 
0.014, 0.0312, 0.0126, 4e-04, 0.0039, 0.0143, 0.0015, 0.0125, 
-0.0176, -0.0115, 0.0066, 0.0031, 0.0145, 0.2961, -0.0102, 0.0418, 
0.0621, -0.0221, 0.0188, 0.0149, 0.03, -0.0163, 0.0083, -0.0085, 
-0.001, -0.0073, -0.0314, -0.01, -0.0025, 0.0142, 0.0197, 0.0159, 
-0.0023, 0.006, 0.0519, 0.0195, -0.0411, 0.023, 0.018, 2e-04, 
0.014, -0.0021, 0.0211, 0.0302, 0.002, -0.01, 0.033, -0.0064, 
-0.0098, -0.0406, 0.0602, 0.0036, 0.0166, 0.0328, -0.0063, 0.0267, 
0.0208, 0.0188, 0.0169, -0.0197, 0.0038, -0.0028, -0.0219, 0.0378, 
-0.0102, -0.0669, -0.0078, 0.0487, 0.0012, 0.0081, -2e-04, 0.0331, 
0.0209, 0.0385, -0.0068, -0.0217, -0.0148, 0.0106, -0.0095, -0.0331, 
-0.0165, -0.0079, 0.0245, -0.0092, -0.0308, 0.0392, -0.0198, 
-0.0318, -6e-04, -0.028, 0.0089, 0.0451, 0.0057, 4e-04, -0.0649, 
0.0116, 0.0015, 0.0058, -0.0101, -0.0305, 0.0239, 0.0131, 0.0112, 
0.0011, -0.007, 0.0404, -0.0058, -0.0083, 0.0188, 0.0289, -0.0173, 
0.0496, 0.0287, 0.0092, 0.0195, 0.0129, -0.0094, 0.0013, 0.0481, 
0.0033, -0.004, -0.0397, -0.0312, 0.0175, 0.0154, 0.0054, 0.0111, 
0.0105, -0.0016, 0.0035, -0.0016, -0.0028, -0.0037, 0.0117, 0.0103, 
-0.0031, -0.0173, 0.0168, -0.0163, 0.0625, -0.0047, 0.006, 0.0128, 
0.0077, -7e-04, -0.0023, 0.0099, 0.0094, 0.0106, 0.0166, 0.0347, 
5e-04, 0.0186, 0.0136, -0.0232, 0.0091, -1e-04, 0.0254, -0.0036, 
0.0065, 0.0118, 0.0064, 0.0183, 0.013, 0.0038, 0.0012, -0.0221, 
-0.0054, 8e-04, 0.0213, 0.0059, 0.0125, 0.0292, 0.0379, -0.0069, 
1e-04, 0.0265, 0.008, -0.0056, -0.0053, -0.0054, 0.0183, 0.0123, 
0.0051, -0.0125, -0.0169, 0.0318, 0.0173, -0.0079, 0.015, 0.004, 
-0.0122, -0.0035, -0.0055, -0.0281, -0.0416, 0.051, -0.0023, 
-0.0343, -0.0246, -0.0022, -0.02, 0.0887, -0.0038, -0.0078, -0.0315, 
-0.0032, 0.0066, -0.0071, -0.0284, 0.0075, -0.0023, 0.0018, 0.0023, 
-0.0068, -0.0149, -0.009, -0.0129, -0.0292, 6e-04, 0.0582, -0.0077, 
0.0244, -0.0091, -0.0054, 0.0177, 0.0121, -0.0024, -0.029, 0.006, 
-0.0026, 0.0153, 5e-04, 0.0151, -0.0157, 0.0087, -0.007, -0.0012, 
0.0045, 0.0203, 0.0028, -0.0028, -0.0138, 0.0077, -0.0195, 0.0022, 
0.0043, -0.0094, 0.0262, 0.0146, 0.0116, 0.0176, -0.0067, 0.0132, 
-0.0092, -0.0062, -0.0092, 0.0102, 0.0032, 1e-04, -0.0012, 0.0133, 
-0.0163, -7e-04, -0.0049, -0.0431, -1e-04, 0.0178, 0.0169, 0.0264, 
-0.0064, 0.0016, 0.0131, 0.0111, -0.0026, -0.0017, 0.0056, 0.0015, 
0.0134, 0.0027, -0.0014, 0.0088, 0.0185, 0.0262, -0.0137, 0.0196, 
-0.0094, 9e-04, 0.0188, -0.0013, -0.002, -0.0143, 0.0021, 0.0146, 
-0.007, 0.009, 0.0061, -0.026, -0.0032, 0.0139, 0.0197, 0.0121, 
0.0123, 0.0031, 2e-04, -0.0048, 0.002, -0.0133, -0.0249, -0.0124, 
0.0242, -0.0208, -0.0116, 0.0029, 0.0154, -0.0069, -0.0214, -0.0221, 
-0.0036, 0.0079, -0.0199, 0.0026, 0.008, 0.0237, -0.0081, -0.0186, 
-0.036, 0.0396, -0.0325, 0.0057, -0.0119, -0.0091, -0.0144, 0.0021, 
-0.0331, 0.0136, -0.003, -0.0383, -0.0363, 0.0172, -0.0077, 1e-04, 
-0.0111, -0.021, 0.0039, 0.0721, -0.0086, 0.0014, 0.0174, 0.0317, 
-0.0081, -0.0031, 0.011, -0.0069, 0.0015, -0.0176, -0.0644, 0.0157, 
-0.0257, -0.0063, 0.0218, -0.0043, -0.0173, -0.0376, 0.0177, 
0.0291, -0.0142, -0.0087, -0.0047, 0.0017, -0.0139, 0.004, -0.0106, 
0.0443, 0.0317, -0.0126, -0.028, -0.0059, 0.0027, -0.0155, 0.0124, 
-0.0062, -0.0356, -0.0315, 0.0415, -0.0067, -0.0054, 0.0096, 
0.0184, -0.1236, -0.0235, 0.0226, 0.0188, -0.0032, -0.0029, -0.004, 
-0.025, 0.0351, -0.001, 0.0296, 0.0145, 0.0105, -0.0251, -0.0019, 
-9e-04, -0.0138, -3e-04, -0.0242, -0.0064, 0.0107, -0.0177, 0.0139, 
-0.0098, -0.0071, -0.0249, -0.0241, 0.0263, -0.0127, 0.0117, 
0.0025, 0.0142, -0.0215, -2e-04, 0.0097, 0.0259, 0.0272, -0.0027, 
-0.0053, 0.0015, 0.0202, 0.0036, -0.0052, -0.0197, -0.0209, -0.0311, 
0.002, 0.0051, -0.0098, -0.0106, 0.0071, 0.0019, 0.0204, -0.0032, 
-0.0104, -0.0231, 0.0152, -0.0549, -0.0267, -0.0039, 0.0208, 
0.0187, -0.0016, 0.0072, 0.0217, 0.0309, 0.0296, -0.0079, 0.0142, 
0.01, 0.0239, -0.0044, 0.0113, -0.0088, -0.0083, 0.0038, -0.0238, 
-0.0339, 0.0134, -0.003, 0.0223, -0.0074, 0.0038, 0.0018, 0.0067, 
-0.0083, 0.0081, 0.0149, -0.0042, 0.0023, -0.0031, -0.0094, -0.015, 
0.0076, -0.0066, -0.003, -0.0123, 0.0087, -0.0137, 0.0046, -5e-04, 
-0.0204, -0.0144, -0.008, -0.0265, 2e-04, -0.0114, -0.0108, 0.007, 
0.0321, 0.0225, 0.0056, -0.0079, -0.0057, 0.0175, -0.0038, 0.0155, 
-0.0017, 0.002, 0.0065, 3e-04, 0.0034, -0.0158, 0.0032, -0.0172, 
0.0513, -0.0045, 0.0056, 0.0155, 0.0123, -0.0018, 0.0092, 0.0129, 
0.0149, -0.009, -6e-04, -0.002, -0.0141, 0.0283, 0.0476, 0.0183, 
-0.0012, 0.0088, 0.0108, -0.0131, 0.0024, 0.0013, -0.0039, 0.0039, 
-0.0286, 0.0047, 0.0016, -0.0091, 0.0027, 0.0208, -0.0069, 0.006, 
0.0159, -0.0228, -0.0544, 0.0106, -0.0165, -0.0317, 0.0115, 0.0204, 
0.0165, -0.0104, 0.0497, -0.0031, -0.0155, 0.0097, -0.0071, -0.0124, 
0.0235, 0.0033, -0.0125, -7e-04, 0.0097, -0.0139, 0.0117, 0.0062, 
0.0065, 0.0066, 0.0052, 0.0049, 0.0068, 0.0087, 0.0245, -0.0029, 
0.0099, 0.0132, -0.0113, 0.0075, -0.0249, 0.0159, -0.0043, -0.0051, 
0.0129, -0.0025, -0.0027, -0.0163, 0.0158, -0.0029, 0.0018, 0.0012, 
0.0145, -0.0061, -0.012, 0.0018, -0.0088, 0.012, -0.0026, 0.0076, 
0.0185, 0.0235, 0.0185, -0.0088, 0.0273, -0.0023, 0.0051, -0.0138, 
0.0114, -0.0015, -0.0075, -0.0014, -0.0109, 0.0054, -0.0045, 
-0.0075, -0.0115, 0.0083, 0.0384, -0.0043, -0.0066, -0.0067, 
-0.01, 0.0118), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1424069985.73567, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), ret_type = "discrete", index = structure(c(1325548800, 
1325635200, 1325721600, 1325808000, 1326067200, 1326153600, 1326240000, 
1326326400, 1326412800, 1326758400, 1326844800, 1326931200, 1327017600, 
1327276800, 1327363200, 1327449600, 1327536000, 1327622400, 1327881600, 
1327968000, 1328054400, 1328140800, 1328227200, 1328486400, 1328572800, 
1328659200, 1328745600, 1328832000, 1329091200, 1329177600, 1329264000, 
1329350400, 1329436800, 1329782400, 1329868800, 1329955200, 1330041600, 
1330300800, 1330387200, 1330473600, 1330560000, 1330646400, 1330905600, 
1330992000, 1331078400, 1331164800, 1331251200, 1331510400, 1331596800, 
1331683200, 1331769600, 1331856000, 1332115200, 1332201600, 1332288000, 
1332374400, 1332460800, 1332720000, 1332806400, 1332892800, 1332979200, 
1333065600, 1333324800, 1333411200, 1333497600, 1333584000, 1333929600, 
1334016000, 1334102400, 1334188800, 1334275200, 1334534400, 1334620800, 
1334707200, 1334793600, 1334880000, 1335139200, 1335225600, 1335312000, 
1335398400, 1335484800, 1335744000, 1335830400, 1335916800, 1336003200, 
1336089600, 1336348800, 1336435200, 1336521600, 1336608000, 1336694400, 
1336953600, 1337040000, 1337126400, 1337212800, 1337299200, 1337558400, 
1337644800, 1337731200, 1337817600, 1337904000, 1338249600, 1338336000, 
1338422400, 1338508800, 1338768000, 1338854400, 1338940800, 1339027200, 
1339113600, 1339372800, 1339459200, 1339545600, 1339632000, 1339718400, 
1339977600, 1340064000, 1340150400, 1340236800, 1340323200, 1340582400, 
1340668800, 1340755200, 1340841600, 1340928000, 1341187200, 1341273600, 
1341446400, 1341532800, 1341792000, 1341878400, 1341964800, 1342051200, 
1342137600, 1342396800, 1342483200, 1342569600, 1342656000, 1342742400, 
1343001600, 1343088000, 1343174400, 1343260800, 1343347200, 1343606400, 
1343692800, 1343779200, 1343865600, 1343952000, 1344211200, 1344297600, 
1344384000, 1344470400, 1344556800, 1344816000, 1344902400, 1344988800, 
1345075200, 1345161600, 1345420800, 1345507200, 1345593600, 1345680000, 
1345766400, 1346025600, 1346112000, 1346198400, 1346284800, 1346371200, 
1346716800, 1346803200, 1346889600, 1346976000, 1347235200, 1347321600, 
1347408000, 1347494400, 1347580800, 1347840000, 1347926400, 1348012800, 
1348099200, 1348185600, 1348444800, 1348531200, 1348617600, 1348704000, 
1348790400, 1349049600, 1349136000, 1349222400, 1349308800, 1349395200, 
1349654400, 1349740800, 1349827200, 1349913600, 1.35e+09, 1350259200, 
1350345600, 1350432000, 1350518400, 1350604800, 1350864000, 1350950400, 
1351036800, 1351123200, 1351209600, 1351641600, 1351728000, 1351814400, 
1352073600, 1352160000, 1352246400, 1352332800, 1352419200, 1352678400, 
1352764800, 1352851200, 1352937600, 1353024000, 1353283200, 1353369600, 
1353456000, 1353628800, 1353888000, 1353974400, 1354060800, 1354147200, 
1354233600, 1354492800, 1354579200, 1354665600, 1354752000, 1354838400, 
1355097600, 1355184000, 1355270400, 1355356800, 1355443200, 1355702400, 
1355788800, 1355875200, 1355961600, 1356048000, 1356307200, 1356480000, 
1356566400, 1356652800, 1356912000, 1357084800, 1357171200, 1357257600, 
1357516800, 1357603200, 1357689600, 1357776000, 1357862400, 1358121600, 
1358208000, 1358294400, 1358380800, 1358467200, 1358812800, 1358899200, 
1358985600, 1359072000, 1359331200, 1359417600, 1359504000, 1359590400, 
1359676800, 1359936000, 1360022400, 1360108800, 1360195200, 1360281600, 
1360540800, 1360627200, 1360713600, 1360800000, 1360886400, 1361232000, 
1361318400, 1361404800, 1361491200, 1361750400, 1361836800, 1361923200, 
1362009600, 1362096000, 1362355200, 1362441600, 1362528000, 1362614400, 
1362700800, 1362960000, 1363046400, 1363132800, 1363219200, 1363305600, 
1363564800, 1363651200, 1363737600, 1363824000, 1363910400, 1364169600, 
1364256000, 1364342400, 1364428800, 1364774400, 1364860800, 1364947200, 
1365033600, 1365120000, 1365379200, 1365465600, 1365552000, 1365638400, 
1365724800, 1365984000, 1366070400, 1366156800, 1366243200, 1366329600, 
1366588800, 1366675200, 1366761600, 1366848000, 1366934400, 1367193600, 
1367280000, 1367366400, 1367452800, 1367539200, 1367798400, 1367884800, 
1367971200, 1368057600, 1368144000, 1368403200, 1368489600, 1368576000, 
1368662400, 1368748800, 1369008000, 1369094400, 1369180800, 1369267200, 
1369353600, 1369699200, 1369785600, 1369872000, 1369958400, 1370217600, 
1370304000, 1370390400, 1370476800, 1370563200, 1370822400, 1370908800, 
1370995200, 1371081600, 1371168000, 1371427200, 1371513600, 1371600000, 
1371686400, 1371772800, 1372032000, 1372118400, 1372204800, 1372291200, 
1372377600, 1372636800, 1372723200, 1372809600, 1372982400, 1373241600, 
1373328000, 1373414400, 1373500800, 1373587200, 1373846400, 1373932800, 
1374019200, 1374105600, 1374192000, 1374451200, 1374537600, 1374624000, 
1374710400, 1374796800, 1375056000, 1375142400, 1375228800, 1375315200, 
1375401600, 1375660800, 1375747200, 1375833600, 1375920000, 1376006400, 
1376265600, 1376352000, 1376438400, 1376524800, 1376611200, 1376870400, 
1376956800, 1377043200, 1377129600, 1377216000, 1377475200, 1377561600, 
1377648000, 1377734400, 1377820800, 1378166400, 1378252800, 1378339200, 
1378425600, 1378684800, 1378771200, 1378857600, 1378944000, 1379030400, 
1379289600, 1379376000, 1379462400, 1379548800, 1379635200, 1379894400, 
1379980800, 1380067200, 1380153600, 1380240000, 1380499200, 1380585600, 
1380672000, 1380758400, 1380844800, 1381104000, 1381190400, 1381276800, 
1381363200, 1381449600, 1381708800, 1381795200, 1381881600, 1381968000, 
1382054400, 1382313600, 1382400000, 1382486400, 1382572800, 1382659200, 
1382918400, 1383004800, 1383091200, 1383177600, 1383264000, 1383523200, 
1383609600, 1383696000, 1383782400, 1383868800, 1384128000, 1384214400, 
1384300800, 1384387200, 1384473600, 1384732800, 1384819200, 1384905600, 
1384992000, 1385078400, 1385337600, 1385424000, 1385510400, 1385683200, 
1385942400, 1386028800, 1386115200, 1386201600, 1386288000, 1386547200, 
1386633600, 1386720000, 1386806400, 1386892800, 1387152000, 1387238400, 
1387324800, 1387411200, 1387497600, 1387756800, 1387843200, 1388016000, 
1388102400, 1388361600, 1388448000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(502L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SPY", "FB", "AAPL")))
```

This is the loop I use in order to perform the regressions. Since there are 3 assets in `RETS` and 4 different dates in `DATES`, it will return `12` regressions stored in `BETA`

```
BETA <- data.frame()
ALL <- data.frame()

for (k in 1:length(DATES)){
for (i in 1:ncol(RETS)){
  rets <- RETS[DATES[k]]
  MOD  <- lm(rets$SPY ~ rets[,i])
  COEF <- cbind(coef(MOD)[1],coef(MOD)[2])
  BETA <- rbind(BETA,COEF)  
}

ALL <- merge(ALL, BETA)

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The answer to 'regression on the "non-zero" part of the data set' is subsetting the data.

Comment: I tried to load your data but I got an unexpected symbol error, please check the dump.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the code @MTk

Comment: I am basically trying to do regressions on the start of the data given the Date ranges ( `DATES`) @Roland

Comment: I think if you visualize it for us, it will help us understand the question better.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik For example in the first iteration when `DATES` is ` "201201/201206" ` and `FB` (second column) is regressed, it will perform a regression for **ALL** values in the given range when in reality `FB` starts on `2012-05-21` . I need some code that will only regress when `FB` begins ignoring all the **zeros**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the zeros with NAs.  In that case the default `na.action = na.omit` argument to `lm` will drop them automatically.

```
RETS.na <- replace(RETS, RETS == 0, NA)
```

or if you want to drop all rows for which there is an `NA` in any column then:

```
RETS.na <- na.omit(RETS.na)
```

To get a subset of points for `DATES[1]`, say:

```
RETS.na[ DATES[1] ]
```